# Android webview javascript not running in all devices

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to run javascript in Webview from android_asset folder. And, the webview woks with javascript in Android[5.0] and higher end devices. But, The webview not working with javascript in Android[4.4.4] and below devices.

So, How can we run javascript in Android Webview for all Android devices.?

Answer (score -1):

Change your webview settings

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
mWebView.setFocusable(true);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    //Handle javascript alerts:
    @Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)  
{
  Log.d("alert", message);
  Toast.makeText(context, message, 3000).show();
  result.confirm();
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Thank you so much for your Answer. And, I have tried with your answer but it is not working in my case. So can you please suggest any more ..?